# TButton on TImage have graphic bug when DoubleBuffered on form is True

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-xe

We are now migrating to Delphi XE (from D7) and we have a problem with TButton placed on TImage when Form.DoubleBuffer = True

Without DoubleBuffer - OK:

[image]

With DoubleBuffer - WRONG:

[image]

Around the button is white border. Without DoubleBuffering is button ok, but form flicker when resizing.

In Delphi XE2 is same problem.

Comment: Double buffering is full of problems like this. I always switch it off. You can achieve flicker free resizing by other means.

Comment: See comment from the *internal tracking system* in report [#75246](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=75246), in short use a TBitBtn instead.

Answer (score 0):

As documented here: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=75246

> Tomohiro Takahashi at 9/6/2010 12:53:44 AM*
>
> ....
>   With `DoubleBuffered = False` on the form:
>
> Black borders = Test Case Error (set DoubleBuffered to True on the form)
>
> With `DoubleBuffered = True` on the form:
>
> White borders = Cannot Fix (Windows theme library doesn't paint button Caption in a way that's readable with GDI forcing VCL to make black opaque which prevents black from being used to make the border transparent)
>
> **Solution: Use TBitBtn instead.**

Comment: Note that [QualityCentral has now been shut down](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/quality-keeps-moving-forward), so you can't access `qc.embarcadero.com` links anymore. If you need access to old QC data, look at [QCScraper](http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2017/06/09/how-to-save-qualitycentral/).